# Finding Eigenvalue and Eigenvector of a symmetric n*n matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, n-dimensional

I need to find the eigen value decomposition of the symmetric matrix in Matlab. But I do not want to use the matlab inbuilt function **eig** Can anyone tell me efficient algortihm. I have already implemented the power Iteration Algorithm but it is not suitable for my project because it gives the best value in  eigenvalue and eigen vector. Looking forward for suggestions.

PS: I am using eigenvalue decomposition several time in my algorithm...

Comment: Have you looked at wikipedia's entry? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm It may help you to find a suitable algorithm.

Comment: @Kapoios yes I have seen. But I am not sure which one to use . I was thinking about QR algorithm and Lanczos algortihm. The problem with the QR algorithm is QR factorization. For QR factorization there is several  algorithms. So still I am searching. I want to add one more thing my matrix is positive semi definite